# MSVS2008 bad compile, skipping code

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have an automated build process, yesterday the build would page fault on start up (bad alloc). I built the release manually and the page fault magically went away. I used the automated build process again with the exact same code, and the page fault magically went away.

Today in my debug environment I was getting a new exception (different location).  At the point the code checks for NULL, then "throw()"s out of the function.  My pointer was NULL, the if was entered, the the compiler skipped right over the "throw(0)" like it wasn't there and continued on in the same function. I rebuilt the DLL and then the line behaved like it did exist and everything was fine (magic again).

I'm just wondering if others have seen this behaviour, have suggestions as to why this is happening, and have any suggestions for fixing the issue. Having a way to determine if the code actually failed to build correctly when it shows no errors in the build log would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Does your automated build process do a clean/rebuild-all or just a build on top of the existing code? Is it possible something is left over from a previous build?

Comment: Clean and rebuild on the automated build machine, locally I do normally just do a build and I occasionally run into linking issues, but I've never seen a single line of code act like it didn't exist before.

Comment: Since the original post my builds have been "strange behaviour" free(without me having to make any changes).  Once a year I don't mind seeing this evil, twice in a short span of time caused me worry.  Just gremlins I guess.